# Unterschied zwischen "sofort" und "sogleich"

Tags: difference, meaning

Welcher Unterschied besteht zwischen den beiden Wörtern *sofort* und *sogleich*? Der Duden erklärt *sogleich* ausschließlich mit *sofort*:

> a. sofort
>
> b. sofort

(http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sogleich)

Comment: Ganz einfach. Es gibt keinen. Sogleich ist veraltet.

Comment: @Max Ried: *Veraltet* finde ich übertrieben. Es mag veralten und inzwischen etwas gehobener Sprachgebrauch sein, aber noch ist es in Benutzung.

Comment: Wie oft hast du es in den letzten Jahren verwendet, ohne eine altertümliche Konnotation zu erwünschen? Aber Du hast schon recht. "old-fashioned" trifft es vielleicht eher.

Comment: Woran (außer dem persönlichen Empfinden) kann man festmachen, dass *sogleich* veraltet oder veraltend ist?

Comment: "Veraltend" ist es, wenn es nur noch meine Oma verwendet, "veraltet" ist es, wenn es niemand mehr verwendet. ;)

Comment: Das war mir klar :-) Aber woher weiß ich, ob und wie viele Omas das Wort noch verwenden? ;-)

Comment: „Sogleich“ hat für mich geringeren Befehlscharakter.

Comment: Nur in Max und Moritz („Dieses war der erste Streich, doch der zweite folgt **sogleich**“) habe ich das Wort gesehen. Siehe auch: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences

Comment: Google News findet sogleich zahlreiche Belege aus der Gegenwartssprache. Interessanterweise scheint _sogleich_ vor allem in den Sportredaktionen beliebt zu sein: Nico Rosberg _eröffnete sogleich die Psychospielchen_, neu engagierte Eishockeyspieler _mischten sich sogleich unter die Fans_, ein Fußballer _wurde vom vereinseigenen TV-Sender sogleich zum Interview gebeten_, und Feuerwehrleute fanden jemanden im brennenden Haus _und brachten ihn sogleich ins Freie_.

Comment: Viele Belege, die man findet, sind jedoch Anspielungen auf Max und Moritz.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die folgende Erklärung stammt alleine aus meinem Sprachgefühl.

*Sogleich* ist ein älteres Wort, dass heute seltener Gebrauch findet. Dennoch sehe ich einen Bedeutungsunterschied zu *sofort* darin, dass *sofort* meiner Meinung nach eine Nachzeitigkeit beinhaltet, *sogleich* jedoch eine Gleichzeitigkeit.

Beispiel:

> Wenn Du A gemacht hast, mach bitte immer sofort auch B

Die Aktion B wird nach Aktion A ausgeführt.

> Er machte A. Sogleich geschah B

Im selben Moment, in dem A passierte, passierte auch B (eventuell, aber nicht unbedingt als Konsequenz aus A).

Wie gesagt: Belegen kann ich das nicht.

Comment: Das mit der Gleichzeitigkeit sehe ich auch so. Dein Beispiel hier ist aber etwas unglücklich gewählt. Hier müsste man meiner Ansicht nach zu "gleichzeitig" greifen. Aber in chirlu's Kommentar sind ein paar gute Beispiele. "Die neuen Eishockeyspieler mischten sich sogleich unter die Fans." - "Die Feuerwehrleute fanden jemanden und brachten ihn sogleich ins Freie."

Comment: Der zweite Streich ist sicher nicht gleichzeitig mit dem ersten.

Comment: Der Unterschied im Verständnis erinnert mich an die unterschiedliche Bedeutungen von gleich im Sinne von sofort als auch von sehr bald.

Comment: @carstenschultz Ja wie gesagt - ist ja auch nicht schussfest, meine Argumentation. Natürlich wird man einige Gegenbeispiele finden können. Persönlich verwende ich es jedoch tatsächlich so.